# How and where do I load these packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, siunitx

I am a newbie and am wanting to write my PhD thesis (Cell Biology) in LaTeX .
I'm using TexStudio as my editor and I get this message when trying to compile.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

with the requirement to use these 2 packages

How and from where do I load these packages so that they are available?
My error output in the log reads

```
Playlearn1.tex  error  line 3  File `tikz.sty' not found. \usepackage
```

Thanks in anticipation of your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is your distribution?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You need to install a LaTeX distribution such as MikTeX or Texlive see: https://ctan.org/starter

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using the LaTeX distribution MikTeX

Comment: See if your school has a suggested thesis style. If not, rummage on CTAN or Google, there must be hundreds around. Or tweak up something pleasing with memoir or one of the book styles. Find out how e.g. bibliographies are to be formatted, ... Lots and lots of fun ahead!